# Define "plate" from Sweeney Todd musical

Tags: meaning, british-english, lyrics

The opening song of the Sweeney Todd musical contains the following passage about his wife:

> *There was another man who saw*
>   *that she was beautiful...*
>   *A pious vulture of the law*
>   *who, with a gesture of his claw*
>   *removed the barber from **his plate**!*
>   *Then there was nothing but to wait!*
>   *And she would fall!*
>   *So soft!*
>   *So young!*
>   *So lost and oh so beautiful!*

Can anyone explain the definition of the word "*plate*" in this context? I can't find any definition that makes sense in its usage above. Perhaps it is an old English word?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here, the meaning is, "The [vulture of the law] removed the barber from [the vulture's] plate."

This is a formulation of the idiom [*off one's plate*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/off+one's+plate):

> No longer a matter of one's responsibility and concern

(Compare with the related [*too much on one's plate*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/plate).)

In this idiomatic context, one's "plate" is the set of concerns one is trying to resolve.

The judge (the "vulture of the law") wanted to get access to the barber's wife; the barber himself was a matter of concern for the judge in achieving this end. When the judge eliminated the barber as a concern, he "removed the barber from his plate".

Comment: Thanks for that fantastic and well explained answer. It makes perfect sense now, especially with your reference to "too much on one's plate". For some reason, I had always assumed the "plate" belonged to the barber and not the judge.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that it's a musical involving human meat pies, I think it's a metaphor insinuating that, to the "vulture of the law", people were just food on a platter. By removing Sweeney from his "plate," the girl was then left alone and desperate.

Comment: On StackExchange, we don't generally encourage pure speculation to be posted as answers.  You might prefer to convert this to a comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

Or, Sondheim is indicating that Judge Turpin removed Sweeney Todd from his dinner table -- "his plate" -- and thus domestic comfort, safety and Sweeney's ability to protect his wife.